# Place a C macro in rust

Tags: rust, openssl, ffi

I  am using a C library(openssl) in Rust which needs the application(my rust code) to place a macro in order to generate a set of functions.

for instance, in C or C++ I would just place the macro in any file and then the library will generate what its supossed to generate.

```
// in C or C++
DEFINE_STACK_OF(FOO)
```

`DEFINE_STACK_OF` is a macro which generates a set of functions using the passed name FOO, like:

```
T sk_FOO_x(..);
T sk_FOO_y(..);
```

which then I can just invoke(I would need to invoke this functions from Rust, so this is why I need to place the `DEFINE_STACK_OF(FOO)` someplace.

What would be the appropiate way to do this in Rust?

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but maybe it's worthwhile to use a pre-existing create to interface with openssl, e.g. the [openssl crate](https://crates.io/crates/openssl).

Comment: What do you mean by "generating" functions? Are they in the library, or not?

Comment: The preprocessor will generate a set of functions base on the macro definition and the params. Check [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace)

Comment: The generated functions invoke another functions so probably I can just call them directly, but was wondering if this can be done as in C.